# Error 404 when acessing links inside subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdomain, openlitespeed

I’m setting up a subdomain wordpress.

Initially I’m acessing like “ecommerce-example.wagnercaetano.com”, at first view looks fine, everything loads, the admin is working fine… but eventually when I try to change to another route like ‘/contacs’ I receive a 404 error…

.htaccess maindomain:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker MOBILE start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile|Android|Silk/|Kindle|BlackBerry|Opera\ Mini|Opera\ Mobi [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+ismobile]
### marker MOBILE end ###

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker LOGIN COOKIE start ###
RewriteRule .? - [E="Cache-Vary:,wp-postpass_dea2198edd9acdc4d43f4b9bf28a886e"]
### marker LOGIN COOKIE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31557600
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31557600

ExpiresByType image/jpg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/png A31557600
ExpiresByType image/gif A31557600
ExpiresByType image/webp A31557600

ExpiresByType video/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31557600
ExpiresByType video/webm A31557600

ExpiresByType text/css A31557600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31557600

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31557600
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31557600
ExpiresByType font/ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/otf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A31557600

</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre "BEGIN WordPress" e "END WordPress" são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WPvivid_Restore
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre "BEGIN WPvivid_Restore" e "END WPvivid_Restore" são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.

# END WPvivid_Restore
```

.htaccess subdomain:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

### Forcing HTTPS rule start
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
### Forcing HTTPS rule end

# BEGIN WordPress
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre "BEGIN WordPress" e "END WordPress" são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

anyone has any idea what could it be ? I tried enable rewriting, symlinks and scripts in .htaccess on both folders… tried map a new config for this other instace of wordpress… but still isn’t working. I’m working with open lite speed versions, and since I’m new to that, idk how to configure it properly.

I tried mess around with a couple settings in the openlitespeed panel, like settings rewrite, symlink, etc.. but it looks like nothing would work.

Also tried to check some data in the phpmyadmin but I couldn't find anything weird or wrong.

Update: I'm using woocommerce, litespeed, astra theme, and wp forms lite

Update: I'm using digitalocean + cloudflare

Comment: What are the actual links in the generated HTML pointing to? AFAIK, WP still has the nasty habit of using absolute URLs for almost anything. So if you had anything wrong in your settings regarding the domain / base path, the issue might not be related to URL rewriting in the first place.

Comment: where can I check that ?

You gave me an idea, I was trying to see if somehow the url were incorrectly.. Then I noticed that trying to edit using elementor.. it gets me to a 404 but when I try to edit normally it works..

Comment: Maybe its some database config that is missing.. I just tried to create a new page and got an error like: "Failed to publish. The response is not valid JSON."

Comment: The you should first of all check what the response actually was, maybe there is an error message in there that helps.

Comment: Are you moving a working site from the main domain to a subdomain? Where is the subdomain pointing to in relation to the main domain? (Why is the `.htaccess` file for the main domain relevant here?) You shouldn't need to change anything in `.htaccess` when moving the site. However, as CBroe has already pointed out, there will be numerous places in WordPress itself that need changing if you change the hostname.

Comment: @MrWhite 
>Are you moving a working site from the main domain to a subdomain?
No, I'm creating a new one as an portfolio inside my main domain.
>Where is the subdomain pointing to in relation to the main domain?
The main domain is in var/www/html and the subdomain is in var/www/html/portfolio-websites/ecommerce-example
>Why is the .htaccess file for the main domain relevant here?
Because I saw some people making changes in those files for insure that the browser goes to the correct domain.. as I said.. I'm kinda new to that..
I haven't moved the wordpress instance,I create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing permanent links to plain.

Idk why but only then it works..

Comment: Can you please add some code or instructions to support your answer?